# Find all the parabolas with focus $F(-3,-1)$ and axis of symmetry parallel to the $X$ axis that open to the left.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

- Focus: $F(-3,-1)$
- Axis of symmetry of the form $y=p$, so directrix of the form $x=p$
- Because the parabolas open to the left, $p>-3$

My computations are as follows:

$(x+3)^2 + (y+1)^2=(x-p)^2$ with $p>-3$

$x^2+6x+9 + (y+1)^2= x^2-2px+p^2$

$(y+1)^2=-2px+p^2-6x-9$

$(y+1)^2=-2x(p+3)+(p+3)(p-3)$

$(y+1)^2=-2(p+3)(x-\frac{p-3}{2})$

Book answer:

$(y+1)^2=-4(h+3)(x-h)$ with $h>-3$

---

Why is my answer different? Both yield the same parabola when $p=5$ and $h=1$, or when $p=1$ and $h=-1$

What approach could yield the book answer?

Comment: It's the same answer, just with different notations. Let $\,h = \frac{p-3}{2}\,$, then $\,h \gt -3 \iff p \gt -3\,$, and $\,-4(h+3)(x-h) = -2(p+3)(x-\frac{p-3}{2})\,$.